# TensorFlow Batch Normalization Dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use batch normalization in a conv2d_transpose as follows:

```
h1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs, 64, 4, 2, padding='SAME',
    kernel_initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer,
    bias_initializer=tf.ones_initializer,
    activity_regularizer=tf.layers.batch_normalization,
)
h2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(h1, 3, 4, 2, padding='SAME',
    kernel_initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer,
    bias_initializer=tf.ones_initializer,
    activity_regularizer=tf.layers.batch_normalization,
)
```

And I am receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 32 and 64
From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'tower0/AddN' (op: 'AddN') with input shapes: [?,32,32,64], [?,64,64,3].
```

I've seen that other people have had this error in Keras because of the difference in dimension ordering between TensorFlow and Theano. However, I'm using pure TensorFlow, all of my variables are in TensorFlow dimension format `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`, and the `data_format` of the conv2d_transpose layer should be the default `'channels_last'`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.layers.batch_normalization` should be added as a layer, not a regularizer. `activity_regularizer` is a function that takes activity (layer's output) and produces an extra loss term that is added to the overall loss term of the whole network. For example, you might want to penalize networks that produce high activation. You can see how `activity_regularizer` is called on the outputs and its result added to the loss [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1288301651c2e9610202a8657ff569ac4bf5392f/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py#L270).